# Python metaclass for enforcing immutability of custom types

Tags: python, metaclass, immutability

Having searched for a way to enforce immutability of custom types and not having found a satisfactory answer I came up with my own shot at a solution in form of a metaclass:

```
class ImmutableTypeException( Exception ): pass

class Immutable( type ):
   '''
   Enforce some aspects of the immutability contract for new-style classes:
    - attributes must not be created, modified or deleted after object construction
    - immutable types must implement __eq__ and __hash__
   '''

   def __new__( meta, classname, bases, classDict ):
      instance = type.__new__( meta, classname, bases, classDict )

      # Make sure __eq__ and __hash__ have been implemented by the immutable type.
      # In the case of __hash__ also make sure the object default implementation has been overridden. 
      # TODO: the check for eq and hash functions could probably be done more directly and thus more efficiently
      #       (hasattr does not seem to traverse the type hierarchy)
      if not '__eq__' in dir( instance ):
         raise ImmutableTypeException( 'Immutable types must implement __eq__.' )

      if not '__hash__'  in dir( instance ):
         raise ImmutableTypeException( 'Immutable types must implement __hash__.' )

      if _methodFromObjectType( instance.__hash__ ):
         raise ImmutableTypeException( 'Immutable types must override object.__hash__.' )

      instance.__setattr__ = _setattr
      instance.__delattr__ = _delattr

      return instance

   def __call__( self, *args, **kwargs ):

      obj = type.__call__( self, *args, **kwargs )
      obj.__immutable__ = True

      return obj

def _setattr( self, attr, value ):

   if '__immutable__' in self.__dict__ and self.__immutable__:
      raise AttributeError( "'%s' must not be modified because '%s' is immutable" % ( attr, self ) )

   object.__setattr__( self, attr, value )

def _delattr( self, attr ):
   raise AttributeError( "'%s' must not be deleted because '%s' is immutable" % ( attr, self ) )

def _methodFromObjectType( method ):
   '''
   Return True if the given method has been defined by object, False otherwise.
   '''
   try:
      # TODO: Are we exploiting an implementation detail here? Find better solution! 
      return isinstance( method.__objclass__, object )
   except:
      return False
```

However, while the general approach seems to be working rather well there are still some iffy implementation details (also see TODO comments in code):

1. How do I check if a particular method has been implemented anywhere in the type hierarchy?
2. How do I check which type is the origin of a method declaration (i.e. as part of which type a method has been defined)?

Comment: Why would you want to enforce immutability? Isn't that about as unpythonic as it gets?

Comment: Python built in types are immutable, too. Mainly I want to enforce immutability for my custom types which have been immutable by convention thus far, in order to help with finding possible bugs related to mistakenly modifying contractually immutable objects.

Comment: I think Python built in types are generally immutable for other reasons. The contract that an object is immutable seems pretty straight forward to me. If you already need metaclasses to debug such a relatively simple aspect, what will you do if you run into really hard bugs? Enforce every contract via metaclasses? Python probably isn't the right language for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special methods are always looked up on the *type*, not the *instance*.  So `hasattr` must also be applied to the **type**.  E.g.:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
... 
>>> class B(A): __eq__ = lambda *_: 1
... 
>>> class C(B): pass
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> hasattr(type(c), '__eq__')
True
```

Checking `hasattr(c, '__eq__')` would be misleading as it might erroneously "catch" a per-instance attribute `__eq__` defined in `c` itself, which would not act as a special method (note that in the specific case of `__eq__` you'll always see a `True` result from `hasattr`, because ancestor class `object` defines it, and inheritance can only ever "add" attributes, never "subtract" any;-).

To check *which* ancestor class first defined an attribute (and thus which exact definition will be used when the lookup is only on the type):

```
import inspect

def whichancestor(c, attname):
  for ancestor in inspect.getmro(type(c)):
    if attname in ancestor.__dict__:
      return ancestor
  return None
```

It's best to use `inspect` for such tasks, as it will work more broadly than a direct access of the `__mro__` attribute on `type(c)`.

Answer (score 0):

This metaclass enforces "shallow" immutability. For example, it doesn't prevent

```
immutable_obj.attr.attrs_attr = new_value
immutable_obj.attr[2] = new_value
```

Depending if attrs_attr is owned by the object or not, that might be considered to violate true immutability. E.g. it might result in the following which should not happen for an immutable type:

```
>>> a = ImmutableClass(value)
>>> b = ImmutableClass(value)
>>> c = a
>>> a == b
True
>>> b == c
True
>>> a.attr.attrs_attr = new_value
>>> b == c
False
```

Possibly you could fix that deficiency by overriding **getattr** as well to return some kind of immutable wrapper for any attribute it returns. It might be complicated. Blocking direct **setattr** calls could be done, but what about methods of the attribute that set its attributes in their code? I can think of ideas but it will get pretty meta, alright.

Also, I thought this would be a clever use of your class:

```
class Tuple(list):
    __metaclass__ = Immutable
```

But it didn't make a tuple as I had hoped.

```
>>> t = Tuple([1,2,3])
>>> t.append(4)
>>> t
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> u = t
>>> t += (5,)
>>> t
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> u
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I guess list's methods are mostly or completely implemented at the C level, so I suppose your metaclass has no opportunity to intercept state changes in them.